# Load next step custom options magento

Tags: ajax, magento

I'm new on magento. I have many custom options in product view and I would like to load step buy step, one after the other using ajax, like onepagecheckout does. Something like

http://tllg.net/dDUy

I can't find any module that do the job. I would appreciate a step by step how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For custom option it would be rendering all custom options

So, u should write a custom script to do this
as if custom option 1 is selected enable custom option 2 disable all